# react-route с express

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, react-router

Использую React-Route и expres 
Нужно по всем путям отдавать файл public/index.html
На сервере код такой :

```js
//устанавливаем папку public за статику.
app.use(express.static('public'));
//путь "/"
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/public/index.html' );
});
//путь "/signin"
app.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/public/index.html' );
});
```

React-Router на клиенте :

```js
<Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={LoginForm} />
</Router>
```

При запуске сервера компонент {Home} отображается отлично,
а вот попасть в путь "/signin", в компонент {loginForm}удается только по средством ссылки

```
<Link to="/signin"> signin </Link>
```

которая находится в компоненте Home.

Проблема в том что если попав в путь `/signin` перезагрузить страницу посредством F5, мы получаем такую ошибку:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Web development\server\public\index.html'
>   at Error (native)

Экспресс требует статики, но ведь я уже добавил папку public на сервере. Как решить проблему?